# Deallocating an object's properties in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, dealloc

I currently have a header that displays a name, time, and a couple of buttons. This header should only appear if an appointment is selected in a dashboard, which is irrelevant here. However, once i logout and log back in, with no patient selected, the header view is displayed. I think this is because I did not deallocate the appointment object, and i'm not sure how to do that (i'm new to iOS programming).

Here's my code:

So I have the interface

```
@interface DashboardVC : CommonVC <UIActionSheetDelegate, HeaderViewDelegate, PracticeServiceDelegate> {
    IBOutlet HeaderView *_headerView;
}
```

And inside the HeaderView object i have these properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CCAppointment *appointment;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *currentPatientView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatarImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *patientNameLabel;
```

I then, in dashboard VC, want to deallocate, but i'm not sure how... this is what i have:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

How do I deallocate the properties so that the headerVIew does not show up?

Comment: It's not a question of deallocating anything. It's a question of removing the header view from its parent view.

Comment: If you deallocate the appointment object, there will be nothing to display in the header view

Comment: Generally w/Automatic Reference Counting in iOS (which you should be using) you shouldn't need to manually dealloc a property or view object by calling that method yourself. Your goal is to visually remove the view. Removing from superview achieves the desired effect and avoids potential hassles or crashes from messing w/memory mgt processes that happen behind the scenes. Setting the property to nil reduces the reference count, eventually adding the obj to a pool to be flushed from memory at some unspecified later time. Don't worry about doing that yourself - just remove the view.

Comment: [_headerView removeFromSuperview]; _headerView = nil; did not work for me

Comment: @kebabTiger share full code and make your question clear. Also [super dealloc] is missing from the dealloc method

Comment: So many problems with this question; I can't list them all. How long did you debug before posting? "How do I deallocate properties so headerView does not show?" That is an [XY Problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) The properties do not have a strong ref to `_headerView` (I hope) so they are not preventing dealloc; **but dealloc is not your problem.** "Header should only appear if appointment is selected" **Prove it with code.** You say Ptbaileys answer does not work; **prove it with code.** His answer is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: @hariszaman You should **not** call `[super dealloc]` when using ARC. And since it is 2015, he should be using ARC.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to destroy _headerView try:

```
[_headerView removeFromSuperview];
_headerView = nil;
```

Comment: [_headerView removeFromSuperview];
    _headerView = nil;

didn't work :(

Comment: can you try insert a -(void)dealloc{}inside your custom view for dealloc all components. like this:

-(void)dealloc{
    _ appointment = nil;
    [_backButton removeFromSuperview];
    _backButton = nil;
    [_currentPatientView removeFromSuperview];
    _currentPatientView = nil;
    [_avatarImageView removeFromSuperview];
    _avatarImageView = nil;
    [_patientNameLabel removeFromSuperview];
    _patientNameLabel = nil;
}

Comment: - (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    _headerView.appointment = nil;
    [_headerView.backButton removeFromSuperview];
    [_headerView.alertButton removeFromSuperview];
    _headerView.backButton = nil;
    _headerView.alertButton = nil;
    
}

I put this and the header was not removed, and still has a blank avatar image, blank current patient, same appt time, etc.

Comment: try insert into HeaderView.m file

Comment: - (void) dealloc
{
    CCLogDebug(@"");
    _appointment = nil;
    [_backButton removeFromSuperview];
    _backButton = nil;
    [_currentPatientView removeFromSuperview];
    _currentPatientView = nil;
    [_alertButton removeFromSuperview];
    _alertButton = nil;
}

I put this in the headerView.m file and nothing happened...

Comment: I set a break point at the dealloc method and it seem like it doesn't even get to the dealloc method...

Comment: For internal elements can you try to remove all subviews from self.view
    for (UIView *subUIView in self.view.subviews) {
        [subUIView removeFromSuperview];
    }